# How to run a python script with arguments via the click of a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

So I've written a program in JavaScript that outputs a JSON. What I want to do is, with the click of a button, I want to pass in that JSON as an argument to a python script.

I am not entirely sure how to proceed with this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/path/to/your/scriptPython",
success: function(response) {
  // here you do whatever you want with the response variable
}
});
```

Any feedback or help is appreciated.

Comment: well, your question is a bit too general, you need a python backend basically, one that handles routes and when that route gets hit call any methods you want and pass the arguments (json) to them, there's many python frameworks too achieve this depending on your needs, flask is probably a good choice if its a basic project

Comment: @Davidlrnt what if both the website and script are to be run on my machine locally? (localhost)

Comment: a website can't run any scripts on a local machine, other than js in the browser, and there's no hacks around this, it would be a big security problem. All you can do is send http requests from the client to an api that listens for them and execute your code there. If it's all local you can have a flask app running locally and listening for http requests on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on one important consideration: where is your Python code?

If you want the Python to run on the user's machine, that gets complicated due to security measures: websites generally aren't allowed to execute arbitrary code on viewers' machines. (Imagine if that Python code wiped their hard drive, for instance.) In this case it might be best to have users download the JSON as a file, and then open that with your Python program.

If you want the Python to run on your server, you can make a POST request to the script's endpoint, and pass the JSON in the POST data. The details of this will depend on your choice of Python web framework (I'm fond of Flask), but the Javascript would be pretty much the same:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: my_json_variable,
    url: 'http://example.com/python_endpoint',
    success: function(response){ /* deal with the script's output */ }
});
```

Comment: The website will just be running locally on my machine(localhost), the python script is also on my machine